# ZPL - how can we increase width of ^BC (Code 128) bar code

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

Am doing a formatting of barcode label.
We are using **Zebra Programming Language** ,  `^BC` (Code 128) bar code

As i increase the size of `^FD` **Field Data**  , the barcode width is increasing.

But how can i print a broader bar code for a fixed small length data.

I saw magnifying factor for some other types like UPC E barcode.

But i dont find any magnifying factor for  `^BC` code 128 barcode.

I put some space and it increase width but not effective while reading barcode

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Look at the `^BY` command

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BY7
^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FD123456^FS
^XZ
```

The first parameter is the width of the barocdes after it. The default is 2, range is 1-10

To change the font, size, and placement of the text on the intrepretation line, use the `^A` command

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BY7
^A0N,40,30^BCN,100,Y,N,N
^FD123456^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: one doubt. when we increase barcode, human readable data of the barcode also  increase or we can set that too

Comment: Do yo mean the interpretation line? You can use the ^A font command to change the font and the font size. I'll edit my answer to show that

Comment: We're having problem controlling the width of the barcode. At BY2 the width is too narrow while at BY3 the width is too wide for the label. Is there any other way to control the width?

Comment: Nope, by default the width can be integers only 1-10 and not 1.7, 3.6

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late to answer your question but I thought it might help others.

I faced the same issue and solved by this trick where I set BC mode to A (for automatic).

example:

```
^BY3,3,55^FT12,172^BCN,,Y,N,,A
^FD123456789^FS
```

this resulted a better barcode width for me than when mode is set to its default value.

Note: still you can change BY to suit your needs.

You can refer to the documentation for more information [zpl BC command](https://docs.zebra.com/content/tcm/us/en/printers/software/zebra-zpl-ii,-zbi-2,-set-get-do,-mirror,-wml-programming-guide/c-zpl-zpl-commands/r-zpl-bc.html)